# MySQL, insert while select from two tables

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I want to insert into a table of two columns, data of the 1st column are from a select while the 2nd column from another select, both selects returns the same count of rows. The result table looks like this:

```
target table column-1 | target table column-2
---------------------------------------
1st select row #1  | 2nd select row #1  
1st select row #2  | 2nd select row #2  
1st select row #3  | 2nd select row #3
```

read a lot of stackoverflow posts and tried a lot but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Is this something you had in mind? [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31e57e/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Write a single SELECT statement that returns the rows you want to insert.

To get the rows from the 1st select matched to rows from the 2nd select, we need some criteria for matching.  If you don't have keys to match on, then you could "invent" keys using a user-defined variables. (This will be expensive for large sets.)

Here is an example:

```
 SELECT fsel.col1
      , fsel.col2
      , ssel.colX 
      , ssel.colY
   FROM ( -- "1st select"
          SELECT a.col1
               , a.col2
               , @frn := @frn + 1 AS frn
            FROM sometable a 
           CROSS
            JOIN ( SELECT @frn := 0 ) i 
           ORDER BY a.col1
        ) fsel
   JOIN ( -- "2nd select"
          SELECT b.colX
               , b.colY
               , @srn := @srn + 1 AS srn
            FROM someothertable b
           CROSS
            JOIN ( SELECT @srn := 0 ) i 
           ORDER BY b.colX
        ) ssel
     ON ssel.srn = fsel.frn
  ORDER BY fsel.frn
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it's too complicated to understand. :-) As you said there is no association between the 2 source "select"s. Good point.